# Knockout Options Object Binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm struggling with Knockout.js Options binding, to an Object.
I'm attempting to create a workflow for the user that allows them to add an Item, edit its properties and then save/cancel to propagate those changes.
I've accomplished this type of task before with jquery. However I'd like to avoid the complicated stack calls that jquery would require. (if possible).

I've created an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/nAE2f/

Whats working in the example:

The Add button, creates a new object.
The Save Button will save it to the array.
The Select Dialog will update with a new Option.

Unfortunately, this is where my progress has halted. While the Select Option is created, it doesn't reflect the underlying objects Name. Also Switching between objects doesn't change the forms properties as I would expect.

I've tried assigning the optionValue to the id, but in that case the Select Options isn't created on save.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the way you binding member name to item. In your case saved item always has empty name that's why select also display empty text. I fixed this by creating selectedMember property within ViewModel to handle selected member and assigning member name to item on Save.
Check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SrNSK/) for example

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I'll try to validate your answer later today. When I attempted to review the jsfiddle link you have the code didn't execute.

Comment: I had a chance to play with this last night. And while the Collection Box is now updated, the form data isn't being updated when changing users. In my search I found an override for a change event handler. I'll try to implement that and post back with my findings. Again Thank you for looking into this, but I can't mark it as answered at this time.